# datatable rango fecha solo me selecciona la fecha especifica

Tags: jquery, date, datatable

mi problema es que teniendo este código:

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#desdeFiltro').on('change', function (){
            var desdeFiltro = $('#desdeFiltro').val()
            var dt = $('#tblPendientes').DataTable().data()
            var anoDesdeFiltro = desdeFiltro.substring(0,4)
            var mesDesdeFiltro = desdeFiltro.substring(5,7)
            var diaDesdeFiltro = desdeFiltro.substring(8,10)
            var fechaMontada = diaDesdeFiltro+"/"+mesDesdeFiltro+"/"+anoDesdeFiltro
            if (desdeFiltro == ""){
                dt.search('').columns().search('').draw();
            }else{  
                dt.columns(12).search(fechaMontada).draw();
            }
        });
         } );
```

Mi problema es que quiero que me muestre todos los registros entre dos fechas, pero al utilizar este código, me selecciona el día y no los siguientes días. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Dices buscar entre dos fechas, pero leyendo un poco entiendo que solo se hace ingreso de una fecha. entonces no entiendo donde esta la otra fecha?

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, el hasta es prácticamente lo mismo que desde pero cambiar la columna, y como bien dices David en este momento esto haciendo el ingreso de una fecha, que solo selecciona esa fecha y no selecciona dias siguientes es decir, si selecciono 01/07/2022 solo coge esa fecha y no los días siguientes. Gracias

Comment: Hola @David081
Ya he conseguido solucionar el error siguiendo la documentación de Datatable y añadiendo el script de la librería moments. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo, un saludo